# Programmatically Press a Game Controller Button on Windows

Tags: windows, gamecontroller

**TLDR**

Have a USB Game Controller, searching for a method in any Windows compatible language to press a button on it.

**Detail**

I have Windows gaming PC and a set of four Ultimarc Ultrasticks built into an arcade cabinet.  Each Ultimarc Joystick appears as 16 button device on Windows, because of a shift key feature I have no interest in using.  It would eat a button and slow response time.  My layout uses 8 buttons, which is exactly how many inputs the joystick has.

However, I'm hopeful I can use the fact that those buttons exist for the device to add a virtual start button to each joystick.

I'm open to using any language, but looking for a method to programmatically press the 9th button on this joystick, which is available as far as windows knows, despite not having a physical input.

I'm familiar with key remappers that create a virtual game pad with their keys mapped to other physical devices, but those come with the complexity of having duplicate joysticks on the system, and don't seem necessary if I can just virtually press this one more button, since all other buttons and axes are mapped as I want.